# Autoprefixer module for Sublime Text 3 does not work

Tags: sublimetext3, autoprefixer

Today, suddenly Autpprefixer module for Sublime Text does not work.

"Error: Browserlist: caniuse-lite is outdated."

"npm update" command doesn't fix the error. I try unistallin-installing/reinstalling module, reboot Mac, close and open Sublime but nothing works :(

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete：

```
/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Autoprefixer/node_modules/.bin
```

change dir:

```
/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Autoprefixer/

npm rm autoprefixer

npm install autoprefixer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made my day :)